# How to get live preview of the video being taken by the webcam in WinJS

Tags: javascript, windows-runtime, winjs

I was doing some image processing using WinJs for WindowsRT, I wanted to get the live stream from the webcam just like we get in HTML5 using getUserMedia().

The CameraCapture UI present in WinJS captures or record the video, so i can't use the requestAnimationFrame() function to carry out the image processing.I want to know a function which can only give the preview in div element using a video tag.

Comment: Check out the Windows.Media.MediaCapture object and its methods like startPreviewAsync, which lets you send the capture to a video element. The Media Capture Sample in the SDK (http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Media-Capture-Sample-adf87622) shows various scenarios of this.

Comment: can you please explain it

Comment: For that, please refer to the "Media Capture" section of Chapter 10 in free ebook, Programming Windows 8 Apps with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript (http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook). This is the first edition, which is applicable to Windows 8.1. We'll be putting out the full second edition soon, watch for it at http://aka.ms/BrockschmidtBook2. This material will be in Chapter 13 of the second edition but is largely the same.